# Visa2 Key Diversification and JCOP Tools

Tags: smartcard, javacard, jcop

I have a bunch of Java Cards for with the supplier claims SCP is 01 and key diversification algorithm is Visa2. I have been trying to authenticate with them using JCOP Tools for the better part of last two days, to no avail.

From what I understand, after selecting AID, the response of `init-update` command is KEYDATA, which should be used to generate ENC, DEC, and MAC keys using KMC. But the funny thing is, although I get `SW12 = 0x9000` and 28 bytes of data in response to `init-update`, JCOP tools says:

> jcshell: Error code: -5 (Authentication failed)
>
> jcshell: Wrong response APDU

My question is, does JCOP tools have build in support for Visa2 key diversification algorithm? And, if not, what is the proper sequence of events to generate ENC, DEC and MAC keys using Visa2 algorithm?

Comment: Dear iMan, Do you have the JCOP Tools yet?May I ask you to share it with me? I can't find it in the internet. please mention me with @ in your comment. thanks

Comment: @User1-St My company has an NDA with NXP prohibiting redistribution of any software, including JCOP Tools

Comment: May I have your email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCOP tools is returning an error because after checking the `init-update` response, the card cryptogram returned by the card did not pass the checks - the key used by the card to generate this cryptogram is not the one expected by JCOP tools.

I don't know whether JCOP Tools supports Visa2 diversification, but here is a workaround you can use:

GPShell (http://sourceforge.net/p/globalplatform/wiki/GPShell/) implements the Visa2 algorithm. It is Open Source, so you can see the entire algorithm sequence in its source code and also use it to verify your own results. Or just use it to work with your cards...